# Searching for non blank string and returning range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a macro to allow the user to first select a folder, then the macro with run through each workbook and every worksheet in that workbook, search for non blank cells in a particular range and return a range of that same row.

For example, search A1:A10 and if theres a non blank cell in A2 return A2:F2 on the next available line of the master sheet.

The worksheets all have different names as they relate to the city of one of our branches.

I have a macro that does it, but i have a feeling its not very efficient and believe theres an easier way to go about this.
It also doesnt allow the user to select a folder, it sets a static one, but this wont be the case every time.
I actually have this macro call copies of itself 3 times, with slightly differently ranges, as in the first one will search A1:A10 and return for example A1:F1, if it isnt blank and the next macro will search T1:T10 and return T1:W1 if it isnt blank etc

```
Sub Search1()

    Dim stgF As String, stgP As String
    Dim lr As Long, nr As Long, lr1 As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Search 
    Results 1") 
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    stgP = "C:\Test"  
    stgF = Dir(stgP & "\*.xls*")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While stgF <> vbNullString

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(stgP & "\" & stgF)

    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        lr1 = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr1 > 1 Then
            sh.Range("A7:F37" & lr1).Copy
            ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlValues
                    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    nr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws.Range("N" & nr & ":N" & lr) = wb.Name & "," & " " & sh.Name 
                    ws.Columns("A:N").AutoFit
            End If
    Next sh

        wb.Close Save = False
        stgF = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Call Search2
    End Sub
```

Comment: If the code is working, but you want to improve it, the right place should be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You might want to look into [Application.FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) for the folder choice part.

Comment: Hey Vincent G. The thing is i have used Application.FileDialog before, but i dont know how to get the choice to go across to the next macro, so the user doesnt have to select the folder 3 times. Any ideas?

Comment: One way would be to pass the folder as an argument.

Comment: Im very new to this. The code i provided was an edited version of something i found online. Im not fully sure what that means or how to go about implementing it into "my code"

Comment: Suggest you do some research, but basically you add a parameter to your sub and call it like `Call Search2(foldername)`.